# Can't install SQL Server Integration Services on Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I am trying to install Integration Services to my Visual Studio 2019. Package has downloaded, when I run it, I see an error as follows:

[image]

I restarted my machine several times, also repaired Visual Studio, nothing changed. How can I pass this screen?

Comment: Have you tried to check the checkbox and press `Install`?

Comment: Checkbox and Install buttons are disabled.

Comment: Have you tried to update VS to the latest version (16.4.xx)?

Comment: I have already 16.4.2 which is the latest version at the moment.

Comment: I'm going to guess it's an errant registry entry that is telling Windows to reboot. Check this post (obviously be careful what you delete in the registry): https://adamtheautomator.com/pending-reboot-registry-windows/ I've had problems with the "PendingFileRenameOperations" one.

Comment: Also, check the event viewer to see if there's any relevant information being sent to there about why it can't install

Comment: Check visual studio installer your setup completed with warning. you should try to resolve setup error.

Answer (score -1):

Prior to installing, make sure you close all programs and services related to SQL Server and Visual Studio. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> and stop all services with a description containing SQL Server.

Comment: First, this should be a comment. Second, it's simply wrong and actually dangerous. Installing a Visual Studio extension doesn't require shutting down the database server, or even the SSIS service